# Bootstrap 3 - Expand element over another without ruining layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently developing a project with **Bootstrap (3.1.1)** and the client wants some elements to be able to expand vertically over other elements.

Here is some example code of the layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="product1" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="block-product">
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product2" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="block-product">
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product3" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="block-product">
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product4" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="block-product">
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a visual guide how the element mechanics should work:

[image: UI Mechanics]

Any element/product should be able to expand. Is there any way to achieve this with Bootstrap, if not, is there any way at all.

Thanks for any help, in advance.

Comment: Position the inner, expandable content absolutely (but relative to its containing parent), and allowing the parent element to show overflows. That's not hard.

The hard part is determining how far you want to expand the element (should it cover the item below completely?). If the size is dynamic, you need to tinker with JS.

Comment: Yes, actually, that's the main idea. It should cover it up completely, but not go over it's height. The problem is, when the container expands, all other product containers are moved, however, they shouldn't be.

Comment: How are the dimensions (width and height) of each product element defined? Are they static, or dynamic?

Comment: Width is dynamic and responsive, I didn't override bootstraps default column class definitions. The height however is static - about 200px when collapsed and 410px expanded.

Comment: Would be nice if you can provide a demo.

Comment: I solved the problem. I used the advice you gave me with the relative parent and absolute child. The main mechanic worked, added some JavaScript to do the magic. Only thing I had some hassle with was adjusting it to work perfectly with responsive layouts. Thank you very much, your suggestions helped a lot.

Comment: If you want to update how JS calculates new dimensions upon each resize, you should bind the function that sets your elements' dimensions with `$(window).resize(function() { ... });`